# Format number Rdlc report

Tags: reporting-services, localization, reportviewer, rdlc, rdl

i need to show numbers `1 2 3` in Arabic letters

i write in text box expression this statement

```
=FormatNumber(Fields!Size.Value,1,-2,-2,-2)
```

but i don't know it's parameter and which parameter can show numbers in Arabic format

MANY THANKS

Comment: the only solution i know is by modifying the region and language settings from control panel to Arabic and from additional setting change use native digits to national

Answer (score 3):

set **report language** to your local language (**ar-EG**) 
in the textbox properties set **NumeralVariant** to **3**

**references**

[similar problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sqlreportingservices/thread/ABC80314-E158-43E2-A19E-8E8D653D9E63)

[NumeralVariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159642%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

**limitations**

1- will not work for strings containing numbers

2- will not work for dates

**work around limitation** *with bad performance i guess*

you can replace any english number with arabic number using Replace method in any string that may contain numbers 
your expression will be some thing like this

```
=Replace(Replace(Replace(Fields!FieldName.Value,"0","۰"),"1","۱"),"2","۲")
```

*complete expression to 9*

Comment: I tried this solution, but it doesn't work, is there any  idea to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can write function in code and use that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Bzu.png)

```
Public Shared Function farsi(input As String) As String
    Dim result As String = input
    result = result.Replace("1", "۱")
    result = result.Replace("2", "۲")
    result = result.Replace("3", "۳")
    result = result.Replace("4", "۴")
    result = result.Replace("5", "۵")
    result = result.Replace("6", "۶")
    result = result.Replace("7", "۷")
    result = result.Replace("8", "۸")
    result = result.Replace("9", "۹")
    result = result.Replace("0", "۰")
        Return result
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=Code.farsi(1111.555)
```

Comment: do  you have code if we want to have only 2 digits for decimal places like 234234.234234 -> 234234.23 like ToFixed(2)

Comment: answer is here Round ( expression, [decimal_places] )
before input in your function like "=farsi(Round(234234.234234,2))"

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Shared Function Arabic(input As String) As String
    Dim result As String = input
    result = result.Replace("1", "۱")
    result = result.Replace("2", "۲")
    result = result.Replace("3", "۳")
    result = result.Replace("4", "٤")
    result = result.Replace("5", "۵")
    result = result.Replace("6", "٦")
    result = result.Replace("7", "۷")
    result = result.Replace("8", "۸")
    result = result.Replace("9", "۹")
    result = result.Replace("0", "۰")
        Return result
End Function
```

Use it for arabic Numbers
 =Code.Arabic(Fields!OrderID.Value)
 =Code.Arabic(FieldName)